# Angular 9 tsconfig.json & tsconfig.app.json paths are not working as expected

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I have an Angular 9 project with multiple projects and one `libs` directory.
The structure is as such:

```
- libs
- projects
   | - app1
       | - tsconfig.app.json
   | - app2
       | - tsconfig.app.json
   | - app3
       | - tsconfig.app.json
- tsconfig.json
```

My main `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      // Shared libs
      "@libs/*": ["libs/*"],

      // Projects
      "@app1/*":["projects/app1/src/app/*"],
      "@app2/*": ["projects/app2/src/app/*"],
      "@app3/*": ["projects/app3/src/app/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

And each `tsconfig.app.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@modules/*": ["app/*"],
      "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["environments/*"],
    },
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The issue is that in each app, the `@libs` path always throws `Cannot find module '@libs/cool-module.module'`. The other paths in the `tsconfig.app.json` are working great on compile.

**NOTE:** My VSCode intellisense is recognizing the `@libs/...` paths without an issue. The issue is only when compiling.

What could be the issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can find 1 difference to my tsconfig file. Do you have the rootDir key implemented?

tsconfig.ts

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ....
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "rootDir": "."
    ....
  }
```

Comment: Didn't have it. I just added it as you pointed, but nothing has changed :(